# Why is it that some properties require "strong" and some do not?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm rewriting an old OS X program and in the process I'm using ARC for the first time. I have a class that contains these property definitions:

```
@property NSMutableArray *variables; //variable names
@property NSData *ebndArray; //boundary energies
```

They are synthesized thusly (I do not declare instance variables):

```
@synthesize variables = _variables;
@synthesize ebndArray = _ebndArray;
```

The `init` method contains these lines:

```
self.variables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.npparxx];
self.ebndArray = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:theArray length:arrayLength];
```

For the assignment to the `variables` property, Xcode is giving me the warning *Assigning retained object to unsafe property*. There is no warning for the `ebndArray` property. I know I can eliminate the warning (and the resulting problem) by adding `(strong)` to the `variables` property definition. Why don't I need to add it for the `ebndArray` definition? Will the `ebndArray` property work correctly without adding `(strong)`?

I'm running Xcode 4.3.2 under OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: Do you explicitly declare your instance variables? If so, how are they declared (please post the code).

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Sorry I left that out. I added the synthesize statements to my question.

Comment: You probably mean *Assigning **retained** object to unsafe property*.

Comment: @fzwo Thanks. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for @property when you do not specify the setter semantics is `(assign)`, which means that the synthesized setter uses simple assignment. That is the two lines in your init method are really equivalent to:

```
_variables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.npparxx];
_ebndArray = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:theArray length:arrayLength];
```

With ARC at the end of your `init` method the compiler will automatically insert the equivalent of `[_variables release]`. Thus, it will immediately be deallocated. The situation for `ebndArray` is different, but no better. Since you just assigned it to an ivar with a retain count of 0 it will be automatically released and deallocated the next time through the run loop by the enclosing autorelease pool.

If you want an owning relationship for `variables` and `ebndArray` say so in your property declaration by specifying the setter semantics of `(strong)`. A good description of how ARC works for further reading is [Mike Ash's Blog Post on ARC](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html).

Comment: With LLVM 3.1 and later, under ARC, strong is the default. See section 4.1.1 of the clang ARC documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership

Comment: Good point. It is really good practice to always explicitly state your setter semantics.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree and always do so myself.

Comment: @torrey.lyons So the compiler doesn't catch the problem with _ebndArray because it doesn't have to insert the `release`? Thanks for the link to the Mike Ash post.

Comment: The _ebndArray problem is not caught because the compiler just sees that the object you are setting into a weak property is autoreleased. This is what it expects for a weak property since weak properties do not represent ownership.